# How to monitor the workers used over a period of time?

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

Assume I have the default setting of max workers or say I have x number of max worker threads configured.

Is there any windows or sql performance counter to monitor the number of workers used over a period of time?

Answer (score 2):

You can run this query at a frequent interval of your choice and save the result in a table.

```
/*
Copied from
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188102/who-is-using-my-worker-threads-sql-server-2014-hadr
*/
DECLARE @max int
SELECT @max = max_workers_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info

SELECT 
  @max as 'TotalThreads',
  SUM(active_Workers_count) AS 'CurrentThreads',
  @max - SUM(active_Workers_count) AS 'AvailableThreads',
  SUM(runnable_tasks_count) AS 'WorkersWaitingForCpu',
  SUM(work_queue_count) AS 'RequestWaitingForThreads' ,
  SUM(current_workers_count) AS 'AssociatedWorkers'
FROM sys.dm_os_Schedulers WHERE STATUS='VISIBLE ONLINE'
```

Remember:

> The actual number of query requests can exceed the value set in max
> worker threads in which case SQL Server pools the worker threads so
> that the next available worker thread can handle the request. A worker
> thread is assigned only to active requests and is released once the
> request is serviced. This happens even if the user session/connection
> on which the request was made remains open.

I suggest you read the following:

- [Configure the max worker threads Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Thread Count](https://systemcenter.wiki/?GetElement=Microsoft.SQLServer.Windows.Monitor.DBEngine.ThreadCount&Type=UnitMonitor&ManagementPack=Microsoft.SQLServer.Windows.Monitoring&Version=7.0.24.0)
- [Perfmon Thread Count vs SQL Workers (SQL Server 2017)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709980/perfmon-thread-count-vs-sql-workers-sql-server-201.html)